Istio Authorization Policy
We're trying to deploy a service that uses an authorizationpolicy. The authorizationpolicy is the following


apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  labels:
    app: centraldashboard
    app.kubernetes.io/component: centraldashboard
    app.kubernetes.io/name: centraldashboard
    kustomize.component: centraldashboard
  name: central-dashboard
  namespace: kubeflow
spec:
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        principals:
        - cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: centraldashboard



The sample deployment works just fine, but we need to tweak the deploy a bit (basically expose it using Istio Gateway and terminate SSL at the gateway), but said authenticationpolicy rejects the request.
Digging Istio's docs[1], for source.principals[*] to work, mTLS must be enabled, which isn't the case (neither sample deployment nor the tweaked one). So I was expecting the sample deployment (minikube) to fail as well, but that's not the case.
Am I missing something on how tls works ?
I tried using requestPrincipals instead of principals[1], as according to the docs don't required mTLS, but they fail as well.
I'm trying to wrap my head around AuthorizationPolicy so I can proper debug the other ones that are failing.
[1] https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Source
